# How to fix the name 'Name' & 'Value' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, and I am halfway throught a task in which we have to create Counter class and use it to create and work with Counter objects. I have run into an error that I can't resolve
The name 'Name' & 'Value' do not exist in the current context.

I have to tell Console, to WriteLine with the format "{0} is {1}", and the result of asking c for its Name, and the result of asking c for its Value.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the scope of Name and Value but after multiple attempts I still can't figure out where I am going wrong

File name Program.cs

```
namespace CounterTest
{
   public class MainClass
    {
        private static void PrintCounters(Counter[] counters)
        {
            foreach ( Counter c in counters) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0} Value is: {1}", Name, Value);
            } **** Where I am receiving the error                ^      ^

        }
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

File name Class1.cs

```
namespace CounterTest
{
    public class Counter
    {
        private int _count;
        public int Value
        {
            get
            {return _count;}
        }
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
           get
            {return _name;}
            set
            { _name = value; }
        }

        public Counter(string Name)
        { _name = Name;
          _count = 0;}

        public void Increment()
        {
            _count = _count + 1; 
        }
        public void Reset()
        {
            _count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0} Value is: {1}", Name, Value);
```

To

```
Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0} Value is: {1}", c.Name, c.Value);
```

You can also use string interpolation which is available in C# 6 or higher as:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Name is: {c.Name} Value is: {c.Value}");
```

Comment: Are you kidding me, it was that simple. Thank you so much, this has fixed my issue. I will be sure to accept your answer when I can.

Comment: @TKeys23 we sometimes miss something small, that's why SO is here to help us all! just glad I could help.

Comment: Just a thought, @TKeys23, seems new contributor, if you could explain why to use `c.` instead of `Name` and `Value` it will add sugar on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't specify in code where "Name" and "Value" come from and that's why you get that error.

```
foreach ( Counter c in counters) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0} Value is: {1}", Name, Value);
}
```

In foreach cycle you take a single "c" element from "counters" array. Afterwards you should specify that "Name" and "Value" are properties of "c" by writing "c.Name" and "c.Value".

Comment: This answer explains why to use `c` inside foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since using a foreach loop, you can easily use the object properties easily by using the dot operator

for example

```
  foreach ( Counter c in counters) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0} Value is: {1}", c.Name, c.Value);
        }
```

or You can use string interpolation for better readability

```
foreach ( Counter c in counters) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name is: {c.Name} Value is: {c.Value}");
        }
```